# Angular 4 (Angular CLI) Error: No provider for [object Object]

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm at a loss on how to begin tracking this one down. Any suggestions from Angular and/or Angular CLI pros would be much appreciated.

I just finished migrating fulling from Angular 2 with angular-cli to Angular 4 with angular/cli and have been able to work through just about every migration I've hit so far except this one.

I'm not at all proficient at webpack/compiling, but this looks like it might be a Zone.js issue, but I admit I only think that since it's the farthest back thing that shows up in the stack trace.

Any suggestions on where I should start debugging such a vague error?

(Not sure this is of note, but (I think?) I have my project configured to use ES (target in `tsconfig.json` set to `es6`) but these errors look like they're coming from `es5`. My understanding is Angular 4 is still on `es5` so this shouldn't be a problem/surprise, but I thought I'd point that out just in case it's relevant.)

```
core.es5.js:1020 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for [object Object]!
Error: No provider for [object Object]!
    at injectionError (core.es5.js:1169)
    at noProviderError (core.es5.js:1207)
    at ReflectiveInjector_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (core.es5.js:2649)
    at ReflectiveInjector_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (core.es5.js:2688)
    at ReflectiveInjector_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (core.es5.js:2620)
    at ReflectiveInjector_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveInjector_.get (core.es5.js:2489)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.es5.js:9562)
    at _createClass (core.es5.js:9605)
    at _createProviderInstance$1 (core.es5.js:9573)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.es5.js:9558)
    at injectionError (core.es5.js:1169)
    at noProviderError (core.es5.js:1207)
    at ReflectiveInjector_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (core.es5.js:2649)
    at ReflectiveInjector_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (core.es5.js:2688)
    at ReflectiveInjector_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (core.es5.js:2620)
    at ReflectiveInjector_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveInjector_.get (core.es5.js:2489)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.es5.js:9562)
    at _createClass (core.es5.js:9605)
    at _createProviderInstance$1 (core.es5.js:9573)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.es5.js:9558)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:770)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:741)
    at zone.js:818
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:424)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.es5.js:3924)
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
    at Zone.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:191)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:584)
    at <anonymous>
```

Comment: it looks like some component is trying to load a provider in it's constructor, except that provider it is looking for isn't an actual provider (causing the [object Object]). It's hard to tell without the code

Comment: @LLai that's actually really helpful, thank you. I was tracking that some provider somewhere wasn't set up right but I didn't think to focus on constructors (which is obvious now that I think about it...). I'll start there for my debugging. Thanks!

Comment: @LLai that's exactly what it ended up being. I don't know if I ever would have found it since I wasn't thinking to look in constructors. Thanks again!!

Comment: no problem, I'm glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

try to use this code in app.module.ts

```
import { HttpModule }    from '@angular/http';
```

and in the imports array add `HttpModule`

Answer (score 0):

The DI services provided in the component constructor to be either configured as ***providedIn:Root***. if not they need to be specified in the app.module (your respective module) as providers.